# Haskell !! operator combination

Tags: haskell

In the following code, what does `m!!i!!j` stand for? Any examples will be helpful.

```
matrixElements :: [[t]] -> [t]
matrixElements m =
   [m!!i!!j | i<-[0..length m - 1],
              j<-[0..length(head m) - 1],
              even(i + j)]

main = assertEqual [1,3,5,7,9] $ matrixElements [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

Comment: [`(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:-33--33-) takes a list and an index and returns the element of the list at the index.

Comment: Might be better written as `[x | (i, row) <- zip [0..] m, (j, x) <- zip [0..] row, even (i + j)]`.

Comment: Please see the haskell tag [info section](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/haskell/info)

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what's imported. [There are many functions named (!!)](https://www.stackage.org/lts/hoogle?q=(!!)).

Most likely it refers to [the one in `Prelude`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.18/base-4.9.0.0/Prelude.html#v:-33--33-):

> `(!!) :: [a] -> Int -> a`
>
> List index (subscript) operator, starting from 0. It is an instance of the more general [`genericIndex`](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-7.18/base-4.9.0.0/Data-List.html#v:genericIndex), which takes an index of any integral type.

Some simple examples:

- `"abcde" !! 2 == 'c'`
- `["zero", "one", "two", "three"] !! 2 == "two"`
- `[0..99] !! 24 == 24`

Comment: I understood it Thanks :)

Comment: The prelude `!!` on that results page is the only one which is even remotely common, fwiw